# detect chrome.tabs event origin source

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am working on chrome extension that deals with tabs. The extension allows to open and close tabs.
I also need to know when a tab had opened and closed outside of my extension, so I listen to tabs.onClose and tabs.onCreate events. My question is how can I determine easily whether an open tab action happened in my extension or outside of it?

Comment: If you open something in your extension you should be able to track this action explicitly in your code. If you want to find a way to retroactively determine this fact then there's no really usable way. Sometimes you can check by openerTabId but it's unreliable and may be missing if the tab was closed or you opened the tab from a background/popup script.

Comment: Suppose I did `chrome.tabs.moveTab(....`, I got onMove event. How can I be sure this event related to my action?

Comment: I don't understand why that seems to be a problem. Use a variable with the tab's id.

Comment: @wOxxOm Please read my comment to Hank X.

Comment: Well, I don't see how I can help without an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can not do this easily, because tab event does not have something like `event resource` to let you track who make changes to the tabs

My idea is:

- define an array in your background script which keeps all the tab id that your extension changed.
- listen to `onUpdated`,  `onCreated`, and all other tab events that you want to listen to
- check if the tab id in that array, if not, then it's not changed by your extension.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work since my app does changes on some tab and right after the user do a change manually on that specific tab. In that case I won't be able to detect whether my app handled the change or not.

Comment: You can probably use a timeout for like 10ms or 100ms depending on what you're doing there. However you're not showing what you're doing so we can't help and if this was asked by a newcomer on SO the question would have been already closed.

Comment: I explained the scenario, which code do you expect? I'll add.